# Matrix of array creation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a 2x2 matrix

```
T = [[A, B],
     [C, D]]
```

where each element A,B,C,D is an array.

Is this possible?

I would like to be able to multiply these matrix, for example multiplying two matrix T1 and T2 should give me

```
T1*T2 = [[A1*A2, B1*B2],
         [C1*C2, D1*D2]]
```

which is still a matrix of arrays of the same size. Is there such a multiplication function?

And also, if I multiply T with a normal scalar matrix t = [[a,b],[c,d]] where a,b,c,d are scalar numbers, the the multiplication should give me

```
t*T = [[a*A, b*B],
       [c*C, d*D]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Numpy arrays already support this operation.

Comment: Start with `T = np.array([[A, B], [C, D]])` and try it out.

Comment: Are all the submatrices the same size? If so, experiment with 4d arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ndarray/array in numpy come to mind.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

Something like:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), dtype=float, order='F')
B = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), dtype=float, order='F')
C = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), dtype=float, order='F')
D = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), dtype=float, order='F')

T = np.array([[A,B],[C,D]])
```

For your operation you may have to write your own functions.